# Reached limit for security function

Tags: pine-script

I am writing a script that needs to call a lot of different securities. I have been using the security function but have reached the Pinescript limit of 40 security functions per script.

I am using the below code per security called. If I was able to calculate the previous weekly close from the 15 min data, I would be able to half the number of times I use the security function. Can anyone think of a way I can calculate the previous weekly close from the 15 min data?

```
security12 = security(currency12,"15",close)

security12a = security(currency12,"W",close[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
security12 = security(currency12,"15",close)
var security12a = 0.0
security12a := change(time("W"))==0 ? security12 : security12[1]
```